# Create build WS in Git

Tags: git

I am using SVN most of time aand recently started to use Git.

Evvery time, I need to make an official build. In SVN,

I would do:
  1) mkdir build1  && cd build1
  2) svn co ~SVN_URL

How can I accomplish the steps in Git?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir build1 && cd build1
git clone GIT_URL .
```

or

```
git clone GIT_URL build1
cd build1
```

Answer (score 1):

"official build" as in "package users can download"? If yes, have a look at [`git-archive`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-archive).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just do

```
git clone <url>
```

A top-level directory will automatically be created based on the repo name. If you want a custom name for it you can do:

```
git clone <url> build1
```

Where `build1` is the custom directory name.